# Javascript alert never fires

Tags: javascript

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
if( javascript.isGarbage() != true) {
  alert('I am not garbage!');
}
```

Why does this not alert anything???

Comment: I don't know JS, but is `javsacript` a typo?

Comment: 1) A typo in `javsacript`?
2) It is really true and not (not equals to true)?

Comment: syntax error followed by reference error.

Comment: Ok, so any answers to this are getting downvoted?

Comment: alert('I am not garbage!');

Comment: Until you actually create the `javsacript` object, and attach a `isGarbage` function that returns true or false, it does'nt exist, and it's `undefined`, which ends up with a syntax error, so javascript is'nt garbage, the coder is!

Comment: Funny... I created this question a while back just to be cute because I found JavaScript ridiculously confusing and counterintuitive. Now it's my favorite language.

Answer (score 3):

If that is your code in its entirety, then javsacript is not defined. This will throw an error when you try .isGarbage() on it. Also, the string you pass to alert is missing its closing quote, as Firas pointed out (I missed this at first!).

It's possible to correct this code one of two ways. You can make javsacript an empty object, and then it will no longer error.

```
var javsacript = {};

if (javsacript.isGarbage() != true) {
   alert('I am not garbage!');
}
```

Alternatively, you can add an additional check to make sure javsacript is truthy, i.e. defined as an object or some other value that will prevent an error when calling isGarbage() on it.

```
if (javsacript && javsacript.isGarbage() != true) {
   alert('I am not garbage!');
}
```

Note: I'm not sure if "javsacript" is supposed to be "javascript." Ultimately it does not matter since neither one have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

jav-"sa"-cript isn't a real word.  Does your code rely on "javascript" being properly spelled?    Is that really your whole code, or is "javsascript" part of some library?

You'll have to declare `var javsacript = somevalue` somewhere first before it can be used in any meaningful way.

Comment: Aaaah, that must be the problem ;)

Comment: I don't know either. It's not like this was a serious question.

Comment: Wow, answering this question was destructive.  :/  Let's pretend I never walked in here.

Comment: @JohnHornsby Actually, you're in the green ;-). Downvotes are only -2. Upvotes give you +10. Even if the answer appears negative in terms of votes, you're net can still be positive (currently +6).

Comment: Yeah, I've since noticed a MASSIVE influx of points from this question.  This has been a weird trip all-in-all.  :D